# Android. Добавить элемент в PreferenceScreen в середину

Tags: java, android

Добрый день. у меня есть задача создать программно новый элемент в PreferenceScreen, но если его создавать и добавлять, то он, естественно, идет в конец списка. Мне же нужно добавить его после определенного листпреференса. как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно вставить элемент в середину разметки с самого начала, но выставить ему параметр

```
android:visibility="gone"
```

А когда нужно показать элемент, вызывать

```
setVisibility(Visibility.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: заметил твою активность ;) помоги и мне, пожаста :D